# How upload images to two different path/places in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

how to store a uploaded image to two different path/places in firebase Storage? I tried this but it isn't working

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${currentUser.uid}`);
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('photos')

const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

blob.close();
```

Comment: Can you share with us any errors or info on why is this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first, you can't re-declare variables like that (`const ref = ...;` then `const ref = ....;` right below it). Second, you need to perform `put` on each ref. So should look something like this:

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

const ref1 = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${currentUser.uid}`);
const ref2 = firebase.storage().ref().child('photos')

const snapshot1 = await ref1.put(blob);
const snapshot2 = await ref2.put(blob);

blob.close();
```

Or if you want to have a little more optimized code:

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
const ref = firebase.storage().ref();

const imagesUpload = await ref.child(`images/${currentUser.uid}`).put(blob);
const photosUpload = await ref.child('photos').put(blob);

blob.close();
```

If you want to be more advanced with this and have only a single upload task, read more here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch